# Python in the latest Raspbian Wheezy

Tags: raspbian, python

What version of Python does the last Raspbian Wheezy comes with?

In LXTerminal I ask for version 3 (python3) and says it is already installed, but when I check (python) it says that the latest is 2.7.3

Comment: try python3 - v to print the version and which pyhton3 to get the path to python3. the python 2.7 equivalent is python -v and which python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for replying.

Yes, I saw Python information v2, and v3. However, in Wheezy the latest version is 3.2.
I wanted to install Python 3.4.2, but apt-get install python3 answer that it was already installed.

- remove installed versions of Python.
- downloaded the 3.4.2 version wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.4.2/Python-3.4.2.tgz
- move to the downloaded package cd /path/to/
- tar xvzf Python-3.4.2.tgz
- cd Python-3.4.2/
- ./configure
- make
- sudo make install

I ask for python3, and the answer is Python 3.4.2.
This worked for me.

Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 2):

wheezy

- 2->Python 2.7.3
- 3->Python 3.2.3

jessie

- 2->Python 2.7.8
- 3->Python 3.4.2